# Difference between .ajaxSubmit() vs .submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a difference between `.ajaxSubmit()` and `.submit()`?  Has `.submit()` replaced `.ajaxSubmit()`?

Comment: Google/jQuery docs.. http://api.jquery.com/submit/. AjaxSubmit seems to be not existent by default: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSubmit/ After a quick Google, it seems that `ajaxSubmit` is a plugin.

Answer (score 7):

There's no such function as `.ajaxSubmit` in jQuery. It's a function used by the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). The difference is that `.ajaxSubmit` uses AJAX to submit the form whereas `.submit`, which is part of jQuery, triggers the submit event of the form and eventually submits it synchronously (unless you have subscribed to the submit event of the form and perform some other actions).